# Format of properly formed 200 ACK response in VOIP communications

Tags: twilio, voip

We have a Grandstream UCM6204 PBX connecting to a registered SIP elastic trunk through Twilio. Our trunk originating calls drop after about 60 seconds. Twilio is blaming Grandstream but Grandstream is blaming Twilio. Each is saying the other is not properly formatting or not reading the packet correctly. Pcap log with single 200 ACK packet in question exported.

According to Twilio, the packet should have an acknowledge something like this:
ACK sip:172.18.23.153:5060 SIP/2.0
Grandstream says they (their unit) won't send it to the private IP address and should be sent to the record-route IP address where it will be forwarded to the private IP based on header info. I'm too much of a newbie here to know what's right and what's wrong so any suggestions would be great.

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 0.119432       96.10.11.12          54.172.60.2           SIP/SDP  1217   Status: 200 OK | 

Frame 3: 1217 bytes on wire (9736 bits), 1217 bytes captured (9736 bits)
    Encapsulation type: Linux cooked-mode capture (25)
    Arrival Time: Dec 19, 2018 13:51:32.749232000 Eastern Standard Time
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1545245492.749232000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.050481000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.050481000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.119432000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 3
    Frame Length: 1217 bytes (9736 bits)
    Capture Length: 1217 bytes (9736 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: sll:ethertype:ip:udp:sip:sdp]
    [Coloring Rule Name: UDP]
    [Coloring Rule String: udp]
Linux cooked capture
    Packet type: Unicast to us (0)
    Link-layer address type: 1
    Link-layer address length: 6
    Source: 0e:d7:c3:5c:55:24 (0e:d7:c3:5c:55:24)
    Unused: 0000
    Protocol: IPv4 (0x0800)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 96.10.11.12, Dst: 54.172.60.2
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 1201
    Identification: 0x0000 (0)
    Flags: 0x4000, Don't fragment
        0... .... .... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... .... .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... .... .... = More fragments: Not set
        ...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 39
    Protocol: UDP (17)
    Header checksum: 0x3257 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source: 96.10.11.12
    Destination: 54.172.60.2
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 5060, Dst Port: 5060
    Source Port: 5060
    Destination Port: 5060
    Length: 1181
    Checksum: 0xfa57 [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    [Stream index: 0]
Session Initiation Protocol (200)
    Status-Line: SIP/2.0 200 OK
        Status-Code: 200
        [Resent Packet: False]
        [Request Frame: 1]
        [Response Time (ms): 119]
    Message Header
        Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 54.172.60.2:5060;rport=5060;received=54.172.60.2;branch=z9hG4bK0d03.870e90c7.0
            Transport: UDP
            Sent-by Address: 54.172.60.2
            Sent-by port: 5060
            RPort: 5060
            Received: 54.172.60.2
            Branch: z9hG4bK0d03.870e90c7.0
        Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 172.18.15.132:5060;rport=5060;received=172.18.15.132;branch=z9hG4bK5d21b0af-3104-4e32-96a7-7e89edd39a93_6772d868_310-9499633517006747707
            Transport: UDP
            Sent-by Address: 172.18.15.132
            Sent-by port: 5060
            RPort: 5060
            Received: 172.18.15.132
            Branch: z9hG4bK5d21b0af-3104-4e32-96a7-7e89edd39a93_6772d868_310-9499633517006747707
        Record-Route: <sip:54.172.60.2:5060;lr;ftag=90419967_6772d868_5d21b0af-3104-4e32-96a7-7e89edd39a93>
            Record-Route URI: sip:54.172.60.2:5060;lr;ftag=90419967_6772d868_5d21b0af-3104-4e32-96a7-7e89edd39a93
                Record-Route Host Part: 54.172.60.2
                Record-Route Host Port: 5060
                Record-Route URI parameter: lr
                Record-Route URI parameter: ftag=90419967_6772d868_5d21b0af-3104-4e32-96a7-7e89edd39a93
        Call-ID: 937861cfda42d874af27d391663108b1@0.0.0.0
        From: <sip:+12485551212@somebody.pstn.twilio.com>;tag=90419967_6772d868_5d21b0af-3104-4e32-96a7-7e89edd39a93
            SIP from address: sip:+12485551212@somebody.pstn.twilio.com
                SIP from address User Part: +12485551212
                E.164 number (MSISDN): 12485551212
                    Country Code: Americas (1)
                SIP from address Host Part: somebody.pstn.twilio.com
            SIP from tag: 90419967_6772d868_5d21b0af-3104-4e32-96a7-7e89edd39a93
        To: <sip:+12486661212@96.10.11.12>;tag=68625bc3-5cb5-4bd4-a255-ce12744a3514
            SIP to address: sip:+12486661212@96.10.11.12
                SIP to address User Part: +12486661212
                E.164 number (MSISDN): 12486661212
                    Country Code: Americas (1)
                SIP to address Host Part: 96.10.11.12
            SIP to tag: 68625bc3-5cb5-4bd4-a255-ce12744a3514
        CSeq: 28344 INVITE
            Sequence Number: 28344
            Method: INVITE
        Server: Grandstream UCM6204V1.5A 1.0.18.12
        Contact: <sip:+12485551212@192.168.4.10:5060>
            Contact URI: sip:+12485551212@192.168.4.10:5060
                Contact URI User Part: +12485551212
                E.164 number (MSISDN): 12485551212
                    Country Code: Americas (1)
                Contact URI Host Part: 192.168.4.10
                Contact URI Host Port: 5060
        Allow: OPTIONS, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, REFER, MESSAGE, REGISTER
        Supported: 100rel, timer, replaces, norefersub
        Content-Type: application/sdp
        Content-Length:   237
    Message Body
        Session Description Protocol
            Session Description Protocol Version (v): 0
            Owner/Creator, Session Id (o): - 1796373137 1796373139 IN IP4 192.168.4.10
                Owner Username: -
                Session ID: 1796373137
                Session Version: 1796373139
                Owner Network Type: IN
                Owner Address Type: IP4
                Owner Address: 192.168.4.10
            Session Name (s): Asterisk
            Connection Information (c): IN IP4 192.168.4.10
                Connection Network Type: IN
                Connection Address Type: IP4
                Connection Address: 192.168.4.10
            Time Description, active time (t): 0 0
                Session Start Time: 0
                Session Stop Time: 0
            Media Description, name and address (m): audio 13894 RTP/AVP 0 101
                Media Type: audio
                Media Port: 13894
                Media Protocol: RTP/AVP
                Media Format: ITU-T G.711 PCMU
                Media Format: DynamicRTP-Type-101
            Media Attribute (a): rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
                Media Attribute Fieldname: rtpmap
                Media Format: 0
                MIME Type: PCMU
                Sample Rate: 8000
            Media Attribute (a): rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
                Media Attribute Fieldname: rtpmap
                Media Format: 101
                MIME Type: telephone-event
                Sample Rate: 8000
            Media Attribute (a): fmtp:101 0-16
                Media Attribute Fieldname: fmtp
                Media Format: 101 [telephone-event]
                Media format specific parameters: 0-16
            Media Attribute (a): ptime:20
                Media Attribute Fieldname: ptime
                Media Attribute Value: 20
            Media Attribute (a): maxptime:150
                Media Attribute Fieldname: maxptime
                Media Attribute Value: 150
            Media Attribute (a): sendrecv
```

Comment: Turns out Twilio support was trying to debug trunk terminating issues, not trunk originating issues. End solution was to create two trunks on the PBX for every VOIP trunk provided by Twilio. Incoming did not retain CID but outgoing does. SIP proxy settings updated to include the PBX's private address and Gateway WAN side public IP address.